# Visual Studio 2017 window is black

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

After applying the Fall Creators Update to my Windows 10 I'm not able to open Visual Studio properly. I can see the startup screen like everything would be fine – but after it disappears, the only thing I see is a white (or black) window – the weird thing is that if I move the mouse within the window, I can see the normal hover messages for buttons (seems that displaying is only the problem, but not the installation itself).

What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Screenshot of opened Visual Studio:
[image: Screenshot of opened Visual Studio]

Comment: Try running Visual Studio in 'Compatibility mode'. Right-click the executable (or a shortcut to it), and set the compatibility options. I am still using 2013 Ultimate and had to tweak it before it could run properly on the same update, I experienced a similar visual glitch. You should also attempt troubleshooting if compatibility mode does not work.

Comment: Try to open it with Run as admin by right click the VS

Comment: run VS in safe mode, go to options inside VS and disable HW acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to a new version, some programs need to be reinstalled.

Try to reinstall Visual Studio 2017 and check again.

After installed, right-click VS 2017 and select Properties, Compatibility mode, tick Run this program in compatibility mode and Run this program as an administrator.